# Retrieving Directions for iOS Maps from plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, maps, plist

Is it possible to make a plist type file with map locations for a table view in iOS.

I looked and I couldn't find anything about making a list of map locations.

At this point in my app, I have each row in the table view opening up to different views that then open up with that address in the maps app.

I am trying to save some space because I am using a lot of Frameworks in this application.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what data makes up a map location? Is it just an address string? If that is the case a plist which contains an array of strings would do.

Comment: Yes at this point, the data includes the address string and then that address opens up in the Maps app. I know I can make a plist file with strings, but how do I make it open in maps and do directions from the users current location to that address.

Answer (score 0):

I would checkout http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html for more information regarding URL requests you can make.

You want to open a URL from your app with something like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino"]];
```

Comment: But how do you do that with a plist file?

Comment: @Steve you are going to have to load your plist into a dictionary for example then extract the values ... [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:somePlistFile];  Then just access your locations via the dictionary.